# Usefulness of IaaS Provisoning tools like Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, infrastructure, iaas

I have a quick point of confusion regarding the whole idea of "Infrastructure as a Code" or IaaS provisioning with tools like Terraform.

I've been working on a team recently that uses Terraform to provision all of its AWS resources, and I've been learning it here and there and admit that it's a pretty nifty tool.

Besides Infrastructure as Code being a "cool" alternative to manually provisioning resources in the AWS console, I don't understand why it's actually useful though.

Take, for example, a typical deployment of a website with a database. After my initial provisioning of this infrastructure, why would I ever need to even run the Terraform plan again? With everything I need being provisioned on my AWS account, what are the use cases in which I'll need to "reprovision" this infrastructure?

Under this assumption, the process of provisioning everything I need is front-loaded to begin with, so why do I bother learning tools when I can just click some buttons in the AWS console when I'm first deploying my website?

Honestly I thought this would be a pretty common point of confusion, but I couldn't seem to find clarity elsewhere so I thought I'd ask here. Probably a naive question, but keep in mind I'm new to this whole philosophy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manually provisioning, in the long term, is slow, non-reproducible, troublesome, not self-documenting and difficult to do in teams.

With tools such as terraform or CloudFormation you can have the following benefits:

- Apply all the same development principles which you have when you write a traditional code. You can use comments to document your infrastructure. You can track all changes and who made these changes using **software version control** system (e.g. git).
- you can **easily share** your infrastructure architecture. Your VPC and ALB don't work? Just post your terraform code to SO or share with a colleague for a review. Its much easier then sharing screenshots of your VPC and ALB when done manually.
- easy to plan for **disaster recovery and global applications**. You just deploy the same infrastructure in different regions automatically. Doing the same manually in many regions would be difficult.
- **separation** of dev, prod and staging infrastructure. You just re-use the same infrastructure code across different environments. A change to dev infrastructure can be easily ported to prod.
- **inspect changes** before actually performing them. Manual upgrades to your infrastructure can have disastrous effects due to domino effect. Changing one, can change/break many other components of your architecture. With infrastructure as a code, you can preview the changes and have good understanding what implications can be before you actually do the change.
- **work team**. You can have many people working on the same infrastructure code, proposing changes, testing and reviewing.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the @Marcin's answer.

Here some additional points from my experience:

- As for **software version control** case you not only can see history/authors, perform code review, but also treat infrastructural changes as product features. Let's say for example you're adding CDN support to your application so you have to make some changes in your infrastructure (to provision a cloud CDN service), application (to actually support and work with CDN) and your pipelines (to deliver static to CDN, if you're using this approach). If all changes related to this new feature will be in a one single branch - all feature related changes will be transparent for everyone in the team and can be easily tracked down later.
- Another thing related to version control - is have ability to easily provision and destroy infrastructures for **review apps** semi-automatically using triggers and capabilities of your CI/CD tools for automated and manual testing. It's even possible to run automated tests for your changes in infrastructure declaration.
- If you working on **multiple similar project** or if your project requires multiple **similar but isolated** from each other environment, IaC can help save countless hours of provisioning and tracking down everything. Although it's not always silver bullet, but in almost all cases it helps with saving time and avoiding most of accidental mistakes.
- Last but not least - it helps with **seeing bigger** picture if you working with **hybrid** or **multicloud** environments. Not as good as infrastructural diagrams, but diagrams might not be always up date unlike your code.